# GSAP add all selected DOM elements to an object, and animate them in/out with ScrollTrigger

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, gsap

I don't even know how to explain my problem, I'm lacking vocabulary. I'd assume this is something very simple, I'd like to use parts of the `animParams` object inside the `init()` function, but I just don't know how to *"paste it"* there.

Sorry if this code looks ugly, I'm just learning JS.

The entire goal here is to have one object with different DOM identifiers, and animation parameters belong to it. H1 has a set of params, P has another, and so on. But I don't know how to pass that part of the object for the loop.

```
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]");

const animParams = [{
  type: 'h1',
  from: {
    x: '-=200', 
    autoAlpha: 0
  },to: {
    duration: 1.25, 
    x: 0, 
    autoAlpha: 1, 
    ease: "expo", 
    overwrite: "auto"
  }
}];

function init() {
  for (const objects of Object.keys(animParams)) {
    gsap.utils.toArray(animParams[objects].type).forEach(function(domobject) {
      
     ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: domobject,
        scroller: scrollContainer,
        onEnter: function() {
          gsap.fromTo(domobject, {
            // I guess I'm doings something very dumb.
            Object.keys(animParams[objects].to)
            // I don't know how to include the part of the Object to here...
            // I'm getting this error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' 
            // But I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. 
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/marxcie/pen/jOVEmVM?editors=0011)

Comment: _"but I'm getting an error"_... please include this error in your question

Comment: I'm only getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' message, that's not really helpful.

Comment: It's actually super helpful, especially when combined with the line number that it occurs on. Is there a reason you cannot include the error message in your question?

Comment: I think you might enjoy the use of [GSAP effects](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.effects).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I know what did I do wrong.

1. my object wasn't really an Object, but objects in an Array.
2. I'm overcomplicated on how to include the object, trying to add an
   object to an object (if I understood it correctly).

Anyways, now it's working. I leave it here, if someone looking for a solution on how to animate DOM elements with GSAP dynamically. (Like adding all `H1`, `P`, `.randomclass` etc DOM elements, when they entering or leaving the viewport during scroll.)

*(I included only the important part, not the init call, registering GSAP and so on.)*

```
const animParams = {
  0: {
    type: "h1",
    from: {
      x: "-=200",
      autoAlpha: 0
    },
    to: {
      duration: 1.25,
      x: 0,
      autoAlpha: 1,
      ease: "expo",
      overwrite: "auto"
    }
  }
};

function init() {
  var i = 0;
  for (var key in animParams) {
    let targets = gsap.utils.toArray(animParams[i].type);
    targets.forEach(function (domobject) {
      let from = animParams[i].from;
      let to = animParams[i].to;
      ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: domobject,
        onEnter: function () {
          gsap.fromTo(domobject, from, to);
        },
        onEnterBack: function () {
          gsap.fromTo(domobject, from, to);
        },
        onLeave: function () {
          gsap.set(domobject, from);
        }
      });
    });
    i++;
  }
}
```